# Groovy String replacement

Tags: regex, string, groovy, replace

I have string in following format

```
some other string @[Foo Foo](contact:2) some other string @[Bar Bar](contact:1) still some other string
```

now I want this string into

```
some other string <a href="someurl/2">Foo Foo</a> some other string <a href="someurl/1">Bar Bar</a> still some other string
```

so basically need to replace the `@[Some name](contact:id)`to url using groovy &using reg ex what is the efficient way to do it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Groovy [`replaceAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) String method with a grouping regular expression:

```
"some other string @[Foo Foo](contact:2) some other string @[Bar Bar](contact:1) still some other string"
.replaceAll(/@\[([^]]*)]\(contact:(\d+)\)/){ all, text, contact ->
    "<a href=\"someurl/${contact}\">${text}</a>"
}
```

---

`/@\[([^]]*)]\(contact:(\d+)\)/` =~ `@[Foo Foo](contact:2)`
`/` begins a regular expression pattern
`@` matches `@`
`\[` matches `[`
`(` begins the **text** group
`[^]]*` matches `Foo Foo`
`)` ends the **text** group
`]` matches `]`
`\(contact:` matches `(contact:`
`(` begins the **contact** group
`\d+` matches `2`
`)` ends the **contact** group
`\)` matches `)`
`/` ends the regular expression pattern

Comment: Can you please help me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144597/regular-expression-and-string-operations

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the programming language, but generically assuming the language does s/// type regexp syntax somehow:

```
s/@\[([^\]]+)\]\([^:]+:([0-9]+)\)/<a href="someurl\/$2">$1<\/a>/g
```

That'll work in most regexp languages.  For example, it works in perl (though I'm escaping the special @ character which means something in perl:

```
#echo "some other string @[Foo Foo](contact:2) some other string @[Bar Bar](contact:1) still some other string" | perl -p -e 's/\@\[([^\]]+)\]\([^:]+:([0-9]+)\)/<a href="someurl\/$2">$1<\/a>/g' 
some other string <a href="someurl/2">Foo Foo</a> some other string <a href="someurl/1">Bar Bar</a> still some other string
```